# How can I disable a button given a predicate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know where I'm doing mistake , but it seems very odd . When I toggle ckeckbox I'm adding items in array and depending on that array I want my button to be disabled or not. If empty disable, else active. Items adds to array for sure . It does get active once when I add, but if I uncheck it , it does not get bisabled.  What can be the problem?

```
activateButton() {
// arrayOfStatusId is an array 
if (this.state.arrayOfStatusId) { 
  this.setState({
    isButtonActive: false,
  })
} else{
   this.setState({
    isButtonActive: true,
  })
}
}


<Checkbox
  onClick={() => this.selectAllRespondents()}
  onChange={() => this.activateButton()}
/>

selectAllRespondents() {
    const { data, arrayOfStatusId, isCheckedAll } = this.state
    this.setState({
      isCheckedAll: !this.state.isCheckedAll,
    })
    if (!isCheckedAll) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        arrayOfStatusId.push(data[i].status_id)
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        arrayOfStatusId: [],
      })
    }
  }

<Button disabled={isButtonActive}>
   ADD
</Button>
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. The code currently in your question doesn't show how `isCheckedAll` is calculated.

Comment: @Tholle don't pay attention for it , I deleted it

Comment: Alright. Still, please read the link in my previous comment and if you create a minimal runnable example in the question you will get help a lot quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code I think you should check for `this.state.arrayOfStatusId && this.state.arrayOfStatusId.length`. Becuse if `arrayOfStatusId` is an aray, it will always evaluate `true`, causing `isButtonActive` `false` always.

```
activateButton () => {
    // arrayOfStatusId is an array 
    if (this.state.arrayOfStatusId && this.state.arrayOfStatusId.length) { 
        this.setState({
            isButtonActive: false,
        })
    } else{
       this.setState({
           isButtonActive: true,
       })
    }
}


<Checkbox
  onClick={() => this.selectAllRespondents()}
  onChange={this.activateButton}
/>



<Button disabled={this.state.isButtonActive}>
    ADD
</Button>
```

Also, if you are using `activateButton` function to change value of `this.state.isButtonActive` and this value is used only as prop for `Button` you can remove the `activateButton` function also:

```
<Checkbox
  onClick={() => this.selectAllRespondents()}
/>

<Button disabled={this.state.arrayOfStatusId && this.state.arrayOfStatusId.length}>
    ADD
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

your if statement is always true. bz this is array,
you need to check array.length to test array is empty or not

```
state = {
 isButtonActive : false
}

activateButton() {
// arrayOfStatusId is an array 
if (this.state.arrayOfStatusId.length> 0) { 
  this.setState({
    isButtonActive:true,
  })
} else{
   this.setState({
    isButtonActive:false,
  })
}
}


<Checkbox
  onClick={() => this.selectAllRespondents()}
  onChange={() => this.activateButton()}
/>



<Button disabled={isButtonActive}>
   ADD
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check arrayOfStatusId **length** property